# Параметры и тип byte

Tags: java

Почему я получаю ошибку компиляции?
Среда разработки подсказывает, что нужно сделать тип возвращаемого значения `int`. `byte`, `short` в типе возвращаемого значения не работают, как так? Объясните пожалуйста.

```
  public byte sum(byte a, byte b) {
          return a + b;
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тип выражения (byte + byte) = int.

Так сделано, чтобы избежать переполнения разрядной сетки. Поэтому компилятору надо явно сказать "я знаю, что переполнения не будет, не волнуйся" через явное приведение к типу:

```
return (byte) (a + b);
```

Либо, поменять тип функции на int, если вы не уверены, что переполнения после сложения a+b не будет.